# How do i add a python package path during runtime

Tags: python

Here is a scenario, i hope you can help me with.

I have python unit tests in `/home/k/PR-TEST/Pr/test`

```
kahmed@qatools:~/PR-TEST/Pr-test$ ls
_apache.py        archive  clienttest  decorators.py   fakeTecoreClient.py  fixtures.pyc     psqlharness.py  servertest   testhelp.pyc  testutils.pyc
apache_server.py  cache    commontest  decorators.pyc  fixtures.py          mysqlharness.py  runtests.sh     testhelp.py  testutils.py
```

and have the package that i am actually running tests against @ `/home/k/PR/Pr` named  (directory named) pref

```
kahmed@qatools:~/PR/Pr$ pwd
/home/kahmed/PR/Pr
kahmed@qatools:~/PR/Pr$ ls
bin  conf  images  init.d  iped  logrotate.d  NEWS  pref  rpa  sbin  scripts  src  test  VERSION
```

Now, i `cd to ~/PR-TEST/Pr-test`, and run:

```
nosetests -s --with-coverage --cover-package /home/k/PR/Pr/pref  `find . -name "*test.py"`
```

but i get erros that it cannot find the packages in pref

Any idea how to resolve this ?

I have to make sure that the python environment knows about the package pr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot (or do not want to) modify PYTHONPATH before you start the program, you can modify [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) during runtime to achive similar functionality.
But in this case you will need to wrap the call to `nosetests` script. Also please check that you do not have case-sensitivity issue with your package being called `Pr` vs `pr`.

Comment: Any example ? of adding a custom variable PR_PATH during runtime ?

Comment: Just use the `import os; os.getenv("PR_PATH")` (http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getenv) to get the value, and than add it to `sys.path`

Answer (score 1):

You should add paths to your packages to PYTHONPATH environment variable

Comment: i want to use a custom Env Varable like PR_HOME, or PR_PATH

Answer (score 0):

You should put your application package in a directory "foo/app" and the tests in another sub directory called "foo/tests". Then run your tests from the `foo` directory so that they can import the `app` directly.

Comment: i cannot dictate that app and tests will be under foo